# best practice for large remote tsql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union, remote-server

I have a rather large query that builds three tables and union all's them together.  All of the tables used for this are remote, the output is used locally.

Would I see a performance gain by creating a view on the remote server with my union query, then selecting from that, rather than have a lot of remote calls from my local query?

Comment: Is it really a `union` or a `union all`?

Comment: whoops, it's a union all

Comment: As with all performance problems, you should try and see which way is better.  If each subquery of the `union all` is accessing only a single table, then I would imagine the performance would be similar using either method.

Comment: There are multiple joins to remote tables.  There's the main table which is remote,then usually 6 joins all of which are remote.  That's per union, so overall the query accesses around 20 remote tables

Comment: . . If the queries are complicated, then I'm guessing that the view would be a better approach.  Or alternatively, I sometimes bring the tables over and store them in temporary tables, if the machine where you need the results is more powerful than the other one.

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a shot then